# How was this equation for pi derived by Ramanujan?

Tags: mathematics

Have we figured out how this series was derived by Ramanjuan?
$$\frac{1}{\pi}=\frac{\sqrt{8}}{9801}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(4n)!}{(n!)^4}\frac{26390n+1103}{396^{4n}}$$

Comment: I don't know about this series specifically, but more generally Ramanujan is **well known** for leaving few written clues regarding his results, and there is a huge amount of literature devoted to verifying his identities and motivating how one might have stumbled onto his identities and (more specifically) how Ramanujan might have stumbled onto his identities. See [Bruce C. Berndt's](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ramanujan+math+%22Bruce+C.+Berndt%22) many papers and books, for example, including [this overview](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/articles/aachen.pdf).

Comment: One might hope that somewhere in that sum (not series)  theres a sqrt(8) in the denominator.  The thought of using irrationals to produce transcendentals is scary

Comment: BTW, I'd settle for seeing a proof that this equivalence is valid.

Comment: We'll never know with certainty how Ramanujan obtained this formula, but there are some strong indications of how he may have been led towards it.  I recommend reading Paramanand Singh's series [Modular Equations and Approximations to π(PI)](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-1.html#.XUz6RDfYpvM) [this formula appears in Part 3] as well as his answer to [Motivation for Ramanujan's mysterious π formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/motivation-for-ramanujans-mysterious-pi-formula).

Comment: @MarkYasuda: thanks for linking to my answer and blog series. For those who don't want to go into too much detail, no one has given proof of this series via hand. All the existing proofs use software like Mathematica, maple etc to do the calculations involved. The sad part is that no one is even trying to do things by hand in this area of research.